# Convert STR column to Dictionary

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to understand how to convert `str` to `dict`?

The problem:

1. I created with group concat (inside mysql) database to dictionary format:
   `{"date":"2018-03-22",
   "amount":100}`
2. I've used mysql connector inside python to import this into dataframe.
3. The dataframe see this column as `str`.
4. I've tried to use Json library:

   `a = df.iloc[1,2]`

   `b = json.dumps(a)#string json -> dump to json`

   `c = json.loads(b)`

Unfortunately until now, the spyder shows this as `str`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a pandas dataframe is required especially if your goal is to convert the JSON string output of the SQL query to a dictionary datatype in Python. Following code shows the conversion:

```
import ast #Abstract Syntax Trees

json_string =  '{"date":"2018-03-22", "amount":100}'
my_dict = ast.literal_eval(json_string)
print(my_dict['date'],my_dict['amount'])
```

Output:

```
2018-03-22 100
```